# How to chain multiple controller/animation?

Tags: animation, dart, flutter

### Issue

I made an ellipse loading animation inside of flutter, but had to use a Timer on all three different controllers. (See example below...)

Is there any widget that can help chaining three different animations?

- I tried using `Interval` Widget for multiple curves, but it did not provide a smooth transition. e.g. `Interval(0.0, 0.3)`, `Interval(0.3, 0.6)`, `Interval(0.6, 0.9)` for the animation curves.

### Sample

[image]

### Sample Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/animation.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(
    new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: new CircleLoader(),
      )
    )
  );
}

class CircleLoader extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CircleLoaderState createState() => new _CircleLoaderState();
}

class _CircleLoaderState extends State<CircleLoader>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> animation;
  Animation<double> animation2;
  Animation<double> animation3;
  AnimationController controller;
  AnimationController controller2;
  AnimationController controller3;
  int duration = 1000;
  Widget circle = new Container(
    height: 10.0,
    width: 10.0,
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color: Colors.grey[300],
    ),
  );

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = new AnimationController(
        duration: new Duration(milliseconds: duration), vsync: this);
    controller2 = new AnimationController(
        duration: new Duration(milliseconds: duration), vsync: this);
    controller3 = new AnimationController(
        duration: new Duration(milliseconds: duration), vsync: this);

    final CurvedAnimation curve =
        new CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.easeInOut);
    final CurvedAnimation curve2 =
        new CurvedAnimation(parent: controller2, curve: Curves.easeInOut);
    final CurvedAnimation curve3 =
        new CurvedAnimation(parent: controller3, curve: Curves.easeInOut);

    animation = new Tween(begin: 0.85, end: 1.5).animate(curve)
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          controller.reverse();
        } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
          controller.forward();
        }
      });
    animation2 = new Tween(begin: 0.85, end: 1.5).animate(curve2)
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          controller2.reverse();
        } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
          controller2.forward();
        }
      });
    animation3 = new Tween(begin: 0.85, end: 1.5).animate(curve3)
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          controller3.reverse();
        } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
          controller3.forward();
        }
      });

    controller.forward();
    new Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
      controller2.forward();
    });
    new Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 600), () {
      controller3.forward();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
      child: new Container(
        width: 100.0,
        height: 50.0,
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            new ScaleTransition(scale: animation, child: circle),
            new ScaleTransition(scale: animation2, child: circle),
            new ScaleTransition(scale: animation3, child: circle),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The trick is that you can create your own tween.

In short, what you want is a smooth curve that goes from 0 to 1 and then 1 to 0 smoothly.  Which you can assimilate to a `(sin(t * 2 * PI) + 1) / 2`  where 0 <= t <= 1
And then delay that curve for each cicles.

```
class TestTween extends Tween<double> {
  final double delay;

  TestTween({double begin, double end, this.delay}) : super(begin: begin, end: end);

  @override
  double lerp(double t) {
    return super.lerp((sin((t - delay) * 2 * PI) + 1) / 2);
  }
}
```

Which allows to do

```
_controller = new AnimationController(
  vsync: this,
  duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
)..repeat();
```

instead of having to add an animation listener and reverse the animation.

The end result is

```
class CircleLoader extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CircleLoaderState createState() => new _CircleLoaderState();
}

class _CircleLoaderState extends State<CircleLoader>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    )..repeat();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  buildCircle(double delay) {
    return new ScaleTransition(
      scale: new TestTween(begin: .85, end: 1.5, delay: delay)
          .animate(_controller),
      child: new Container(
        height: 10.0,
        width: 10.0,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: Colors.grey[300],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
      child: new Container(
        width: 100.0,
        height: 50.0,
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            buildCircle(.0),
            buildCircle(.2),
            buildCircle(.4),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestTween extends Tween<double> {
  final double delay;

  TestTween({double begin, double end, this.delay})
      : super(begin: begin, end: end);

  @override
  double lerp(double t) {
    return super.lerp((sin((t - delay) * 2 * PI) + 1) / 2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Really nice, I was hoping there is widget for that, but this works super well and reduced the redundancy of having multiple controllers/listener. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to chain animations, it's all about `Tween`. You can use `myTween.chain(anotherTween).animate(_controller)`

In this case it wasn't needed. But it's possible.

Comment: Excellent, that sounds like what I need! At some point  I do want to chain Tween to make a recoil, jerkback like animation effect. e.g: Tween(begin: .85, end: 1.5,).chain(new Tween(1.5, 1.0)) Thank you again!

Comment: I don't think chain is what you are looking for. For me it seems to "multiply" the Tweens. I think TweenSequence is better suited to this application.

Comment: That class didn't exists at the time of this answer though